# chrome.app.window Alternative

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

so currently I have a packaged Chrome app, which uses `chrome.app.window.create()` to create frameless Notifications. Since Chrome Apps will be discontinued in the near future I am currently looking for alternatives.

I am trying now to emulate the same behavior in a Chrome Extension, but I have only found `chrome.windows.create()` where I can open popups, but they can't be made frameless apparently.

I have also tried `chrome.notifications` but they are not customizable enough for my needs.

Do any of you guys know a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's about it. You can't emulate this behavior with extensions.

Add to that list a possibility to inject DOM in the currently opened page, which you can style, but it's complicated, requires very heavy permissions to do at will at any page, will be confined to the browser viewport and still won't work in some edge cases.